# Generate a new image on a button press in Swift AppleWatch

Tags: image, swift, apple-watch, arc4random

Okay so I have 4 images, and they are named in sequence 'colour1.jpg', colour2.jpg, 'colour3.jpg', 'colour4.jpg'. Each of these images will act as a button background image.

The idea is there are 4 buttons on the screen, and each time one of the buttons is pressed, the images all change randomly on each of the buttons.

I am using the arc4random_uniform to randomise the images. But it doesn't work, at the moment, if the user presses one of the buttons, a random image is chosen, but it is identical across all 4 buttons. and then it won't ever change from that image. ie. if you press the same or another button, nothing happens. It just remains on the previous image.

I am new to swift so appreciate your patience with me, but would really like to learn where I'm going wrong.

```
class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

    @IBOutlet var blueColour: WKInterfaceButton!
    @IBOutlet var pinkColour: WKInterfaceButton!
    @IBOutlet var greenColour: WKInterfaceButton!
    @IBOutlet var yellowColour: WKInterfaceButton!


    var randomImageA1 = arc4random_uniform(4)
    var randomImageA2 = arc4random_uniform(4)
    var randomImageA3 = arc4random_uniform(4)
    var randomImageA4 = arc4random_uniform(4)

    var randomImageB1 = arc4random_uniform(4)
    var randomImageB2 = arc4random_uniform(4)
    var randomImageB3 = arc4random_uniform(4)
    var randomImageB4 = arc4random_uniform(4)

    var randomImageC1 = arc4random_uniform(4)
    var randomImageC2 = arc4random_uniform(4)
    var randomImageC3 = arc4random_uniform(4)
    var randomImageC4 = arc4random_uniform(4)

    var randomImageD1 = arc4random_uniform(4)
    var randomImageD2 = arc4random_uniform(4)
    var randomImageD3 = arc4random_uniform(4)
    var randomImageD4 = arc4random_uniform(4)

    @IBAction func onePressed() {

        blueColour.setBackgroundImageNamed("colour\(randomImageA1).jpg")
        pinkColour.setBackgroundImageNamed("colour\(randomImageA2).jpg")
        greenColour.setBackgroundImageNamed("colour\(randomImageA3).jpg")
        yellowColour.setBackgroundImageNamed("colour\(randomImageA4).jpg")

    }

    @IBAction func twoPressed() {

        blueColour.setBackgroundImageNamed("colour\(randomImageB1).jpg")
        pinkColour.setBackgroundImageNamed("colour\(randomImageB2).jpg")
        greenColour.setBackgroundImageNamed("colour\(randomImageB3).jpg")
        yellowColour.setBackgroundImageNamed("colour\(randomImageB4).jpg")

    }

    @IBAction func threePressed() {

        blueColour.setBackgroundImageNamed("colour\(randomImageC1).jpg")
        pinkColour.setBackgroundImageNamed("colour\(randomImageC2).jpg")
        greenColour.setBackgroundImageNamed("colour\(randomImageC3).jpg")
        yellowColour.setBackgroundImageNamed("colour\(randomImageC4).jpg")

    }

    @IBAction func fourPressed() {

        blueColour.setBackgroundImageNamed("colour\(randomImageD1).jpg")
        pinkColour.setBackgroundImageNamed("colour\(randomImageD2).jpg")
        greenColour.setBackgroundImageNamed("colour\(randomImageD3).jpg")
        yellowColour.setBackgroundImageNamed("colour\(randomImageD4).jpg")

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only calling `randomImage = arc4random_uniform(5)` one time. If that function randomly chooses an image for you, then you need to call it before every call to `setBackgroundImage()`

Your success of randomness will also depend on how you are randomizing your image within `randomImage = arc4random_uniform(5)`.  Hard to say whether that will always return the same image or not without seeing your implementation of randomness.

Example:

```
@IBOutlet var blueColour: WKInterfaceButton!
@IBOutlet var pinkColour: WKInterfaceButton!
@IBOutlet var greenColour: WKInterfaceButton!
@IBOutlet var yellowColour: WKInterfaceButton!


var randomImage

@IBAction func onePressed() {
    randomImage = arc4random_uniform(4)
    blueColour.setBackgroundImageNamed("colour\(randomImage).jpg")
    randomImage = arc4random_uniform(4)
    pinkColour.setBackgroundImageNamed("colour\(randomImage).jpg")
    randomImage = arc4random_uniform(4)
    greenColour.setBackgroundImageNamed("colour\(randomImage).jpg")
    randomImage = arc4random_uniform(4)
    yellowColour.setBackgroundImageNamed("colour\(randomImage).jpg")

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mike - So i have updated my code above. I have added arc4random_uniform generators for each image. They now generate a image background for each button on the screen. Is the code above correct that i have done? It just seems a bit long winded for what i need to do. Is there another/easier/better way i could have written it? Also, there is still some strange behaviour with it. If i click say the blueColour button to generate all the random images, if i then press it again, the images won't change for any button, i have to press a different button. Do you know why this is? thanks

Comment: I updated to provide an example. You are running into an issue with variable scoping. In general, assignments that you make outside of a function will occur only once. You want to generate randomness on every button press, so the randomness call needs to occur inside the function.

Comment: Thanks @Mike, I will try amending this later and let you know how I get on. The makes sense about the scoping so thanks for the explanation.

Comment: I have done @Mike, thanks. The only thing I still can't figure out is how to stop the image showing twice when all 4 images are randomly generated. I guess i need to do some sort of check, but i just can't figure out how to do that in this situation. Can you help with this at all? Thanks again Mike.